# not be able to create Access Control Page

Tags: apex, sql-grant, privilege

APEX: The current application schema does not have CREATE TABLE, CREATE TRIGGER, CREATE SEQUENCE privilege and will not be able to create Access Control Page.

what the grant query could solve it, i have checked with query(grant connect, resource,dba to user and to the schema too...)

Comment: Is this question about Oracle Application Express? If yes, use tag `oracle-apex`.

Comment: yes, it was on creating Access Control Page.

Comment: now i have solved it with query "GRANT All PRIVILEGE TO user;
"

Answer (score 0):

So, "GRANT All PRIVILEGE TO user;" is not always the solution to go for.

The issue I figured out is even when there is a role having all the grants, Apex does not recognize it and won't be able to create the needed tables.

Error message that will show up in the wizard:

> The current application schema does not have CREATE TABLE, CREATE TRIGGER, CREATE SEQUENCE privilege and will not be able to create Access Control Page.

So what I did is grant each privilege again:

```
grant create table to <user>;
grant create trigger to <user>;
grant create sequence to <user>;
```

then it worked.